# Function to log in to multiple websites with python

Tags: python-3.x, authentication

i am new to python, but very eager to learn. I am trying to build a function to be able to log into multiple webpages (one at a time) make several actions and download a report at the end.

the final part of the problem i was able to resolve with web-scratch.

but now i am stuck, and i cant find a way to resolve the first problem (log to the first site, run the code that i already have and at the end go to the next site.

this is the code at the moment for the first part of the problem:

```
from optparse import OptionParser
import sys
from mechanize import Browser, CookieJar, Request, urlopen


accounts = [
    {'site': 'https://something', 'user': 'username', 'pass': 'password'},
    {'site': 'https://something3','user': 'username2', 'pass': 'password2'}
    ]


class WebsiteAccount(object):

    def __init__(self, ipaddr, username, password, browser):
        self.ipaddr = ipaddr
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.browser = browser
        self.cookiejar = CookieJar()
        self.browser.set_cookiejar(self.cookiejar)

    def login(self):
        self.browser.open('http://'+self.ipaddr+'/login.html')
        self.browser.select_form(name='loginform')
        self.browser.form.set_value(self.username, name='username')
        self.browser.form.set_value(self.password, name='password')
        resp = self.browser.submit()
        print('Logging into account %s@%s ...' % (self.username, self.ipaddr)),
        if resp.geturl().endswith('/login.html'):
            print('FAILED!')
            sys.exit(1)
        print(' OK')

    def logout(self):
        print ('Logging out from account %s@%s...' % (self.username, self.ipaddr),
        self.browser.open('http://'+self.ipaddr+'/logout.html'),
        self.browser.close(),
        print('OK')


def main():
    parser = OptionParser()
    parser.add_option('-d', '--debug', action='store_true', dest='debug', default=False)
    parser.add_option('-v', '--verbose', action='store_true', dest='verbose', default=False)
    (opts, args) = parser.parse_args()
    for account in accounts:
        browser = Browser()
        browser.set_handle_referer(True)
        browser.set_handle_redirect(True)
        browser.set_handle_robots(False)
        bs = WebsiteAccount(account['ipaddr'],
                        account['user'],
                        account['pass'],
                        browser)
    # DEBUG
        if opts.debug == True:
            browser.set_debug_redirects(True)
            browser.set_debug_responses(True)
            browser.set_debug_http(True)
    bs.login()
        try:
            # ... do some stuff
            # save cookies here?  
            pass
        finally:
            # you shouldn't use this if you are interested in the login cookies
            bs.logout()


if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

but im not sure if i am  approaching this the right way. is there any simpler way of doing this?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with how you're approaching this.  Is it working as you want and you're just checking if this is the right way to do it, or are you running into an issue with this approach and you're looking for help solving it?

Comment: it is not working, im am receiving the error:  
def main():
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

and i was also windering if there is some simlper whay of doing this...

Comment: Syntaz Error means that your code is not formatted correctly.  "def main()" doesn't appear anywhere in your question, so your error is with a part of your program that you didn't post.  Can you edit your question to include that part of your code?

Comment: Done, thanks for the help by the way :)

Comment: No problem! A few issues I see: Every line of your logout() function ends in a comma (no reason for this).  And you forgot to close the parentheses of the print function in the first line of your logout function.  And lastly, you have an indentation issue - either the `bs.loging()` line or the `try:` line is at the incorrect indentation level.  Let me know if fixing those issues solves your problem!

Comment: i only realized at this moment that the module mechanized only works in python 2, i am running python 3 :( my bad, sorry for wasting your time Christopher, and thank you anyway... i am going to try and find another way of solving this problem...

Comment: No worries, good luck!